# Get buffer around line string with varying distance

Tags: numpy, geometry, shapely

Given a linestring and an equally long list of distances (scalars), how can I get a new polyline that is left (or right) to the original one with an offset as specified at the respective position in the list? Essentially what [shapely.offset_curve()](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.offset_curve.html) would do, but with a non-fixed offset distance.

[image]

Comment: Build perpendiculars at needed points. Calculate wrinkle points as intersection of neighbor offset segments. And `varying distance` is doubtful term - how frequently does offset change?

Comment: I am also interested in this question: I actually asked a very similar question before here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/452116/buffer-a-polyline-by-variable-distance
A answer is given there using QGis, but would love to see a more shapely'esk method.
Implementation does not seem trivial to write like the other comment suggested, because of rounded corners etc.

Comment: Adding a thumbs up to the following issue will help to get the feature in shapely on longer term ;-): https://github.com/libgeos/geos/issues/529

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to buffer the vertexes/points individually, calculating the convex hull for each connected buffered vertex/point pair and then calculating the dissolved union of these convex hulls.

```
import shapely

line = shapely.LineString([(0,0), (5, 6), (8, -4), (16, 9)])
buffer_sizes = [1, 2, 3, 4]

points = [shapely.Point(coords) for coords in line.coords]

buffered_points = [
   point.buffer(s) for s, point in zip(buffered_points, points)
]

convex_hulls = []
for i in range(len(buffered_points)-1):
    convex_hulls.append(
        shapely.convex_hull(
            shapely.union(
                buffered_points[i], 
                buffered_points[i+1]
            )
        )
    )

buffered_line = shapely.union_all(convex_hulls)

offset_lines = shapely.difference(
    shapely.difference(buffered_line.exterior, buffered_points[0]),
    buffered_points[-1]
)
```

There is probably a more elegant and efficient method for this but it seems to solve your problem.

Comment: This is quite close to what I was looking for! However, it returns a POLYGON, while I'd preferably need two single LINESTRINGs instead, one being "right" of the reference line, the other being "left" of it. In other words, I'd need the "left" and "right" boundaries of the polygon as polylines. How can we achieve that?

Comment: Ah yes, I must have missed that part of the question before. I edited the answer now.